# PHP : Related Issue (View Logs From Hyperlink)

Tags: php

I just completed something about using C# to send http Requests to the db from a php file. Now I want to view the data. The database arranges the data in form of hyperlinks. Now here is what I want: for instance I click the hyperlink, it opens a blank page, then on the new page it connects to the database and fetches the logs and pastes for me to see the data that was sent via C# http request.

How do I get to do this?

I was thinking of doing something like this...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <a href="data.php?data=formdata">http://www.localhost/personalData/</a>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: "I was thinking of doing something like this..."  Have you actually tried anything? Ask a specific question about a specific problem that you are having.

Comment: Yes, you should try that.  Only then will you have a real question.